# In this example how would I make filenames appended with "0000"+1 instead of "0"+1?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I know this is a gimme, but I'm trying to make the filenames serialized with four digits instead of one. This function is for exporting PNG files from layers within Adobe Illustrator. Let me know if you ever need icons - much respect.

```
var n = document.layers.length;
    hideAllLayers ();
    for(var i=n-1, k=0; i>=0; i--, k++)
    {
        //hideAllLayers();
        var layer = document.layers[i];
        layer.visible = true;


        var file = new File(folder.fsName + '/' +filename+ '-' + k +".png");

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
        layer.visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `util.printf` (see [the Acrobat API, page 720](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)):

```
var file = new File(util.printf("%s/%s-%04d.png", folder.fsName, filename, k));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I may embark on learning JS for the Acrobat API

Answer (score 1):

You can pad your number to the left and take the last four characters like this:

```
var i = 9;
var num = ("0000"+i);
var str = "filename"+(num.substring(num.length-4));  //filename0009
```

Or shorter

```
str = ("0000" + i).slice(-4)
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22707763/1864610)

Comment: Note that this truncates numbers of 5 or more digits to the last four digits. This isn't bad, but is something to be aware of.

Comment: @rampion Read the question: the requirement was to serialise filenames with four digits. We must assume that the OP never has more than 10000 files (0 - 9999)

Comment: I agree, I just figured it was worth pointing out.